# Probability of finger print

Tags: probability, statistics

> A person is a suspect in a criminal investigation, and there is a 25% chance they are guilty (event G). If they are guilty, there is a 90% chance their fingerprints would be found at the crime scene. If they are not guilty, there is a 10% chance their fingerprints would be found.
>
> Suppose in addition to fingerprints, DNA evidence is found (event D).  The prob-ability of leaving DNA evidence is also 10% if they are not guilty and 90% if they are  guilty.   Leaving  evidence  of  different  types  is  independent,  conditional  on  their guilt/innocence.  What is the probability that the person is guilty, given BOTH  fingerprints and DNA evidence are found?

We want $P(G|DF) = P(GDF)/P(DF)$, we know $P(D | \overline{G}) = 0.1, P(D | G ) = 0.9$

Can I get a hint?

Comment: Posting images of text is highly discouraged on this site as it does not enable others to find this question later.

Answer (score 3):

For any events $a$ and $b$,
$$P(a|b) = P(b|a)P(a)/P(b)$$
$$P(b) = P(b|a)P(a) + P(b|\bar a)P(\bar a)$$
therefore
$$P(a|b) = {P(b|a)P(a) \over P(b|a)P(a) + P(b|\bar a)P(\bar a)}$$

$$P(G|DF) = {P(DF|G)P(G) \over P(DF|G)P(G) + P(DF|\bar G)P(\bar G)}$$
$$P(G|DF) = {0.9^2\cdot 0.25 \over 0.9^2 \cdot 0.25 + 0.1^2 \cdot 0.75} = {27 \over 28} $$